# C++ variadic template with doubles

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

The following code

```
#include <initializer_list>
#include <vector>

template<int ...>
const std::vector<int>*make_from_ints(int args...)
{ return new std::vector<int>(std::initializer_list<int>{args}); }
```

is compiling (with GCC 6.3, on Debian/Sid/x86-64) correctly, and I expect it for a call like

```
auto vec = make_from_ints(1,2,3);
```

to return a pointer to some vector of integers containing 1, 2, 3.

However, if I replace `int` by `double`, that is if I add the following (in the same `basiletemplates.cc` file ...) code:

```
template<double ...>
const std::vector<double>*make_from_doubles(double args...)
{ return new std::vector<double>(std::initializer_list<double>{args}); }
```

I'm getting a compile error:

```
basiletemplates.cc:8:17: error: ‘double’ is not a valid type
                for a template non-type parameter
 template<double ...>
                 ^~~
```

and I don't understand why. After all both `int` and `double` are scalar numerical POD types (predefined in the C++11 standard).

How to get a template variadic function to be able to code:

```
auto dvec = make_from_doubles(-1.0, 2.0, 4.0);
```

and get a pointer to some vector of doubles containing -1.0, 2.0, 4.0 ?

BTW, compiling for C++14 (with `g++ -Wall -std=c++14 -c basiletemplates.cc`), and using `clang++` (version 3.8.1) instead of `g++` dont change anything.

Comment: `int args...` is parsed as `int args, ...`, your template's definition is simply wrong

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
template<int ...>
const std::vector<int>*make_from_ints(int args...)
{ return new std::vector<int>(std::initializer_list<int>{args}); }
```

The snippet above has a multitude of issues:

- Returning a `const std::vector<int>*` instead of a `std::vector<int>` and unnecessarily using dynamic allocation.

  - Even if you wanted to use dynamic allocation, you should use `std::make_unique` instead of `new`.
- You defined `make_from_ints` to be template function that takes any amount of `int` template parameters, but you're not giving those `int`s a name - you cannot ever use them!
- Your signature is actually being parsed as `make_from_ints(int args, ...)` - this is a C `va_args` signature that has nothing to do with variadic templates.

  - The correct syntax for an argument pack is `type... name`.

If you want to accept any number of arguments of a specific type that works nicely with *template argument deduction*, the easiest way is to use a regular *variadic template* that accepts an arbitrary amount of types and `static_assert`s their type *(or uses `std::enable_if` for SFINAE-friendliness)*. Here's an example:

```
template <typename... Ts>
auto make_from_ints(Ts... xs) 
{ 
    static_assert((std::is_same<Ts, int>::value && ...));
    return std::vector<int>{xs...};
}

template <typename... Ts>
auto make_from_doubles(Ts... xs) 
{ 
    static_assert((std::is_same<Ts, double>::value && ...));
    return std::vector<double>{xs...};
}
```

Usage:

```
for(auto x : make_from_ints(1,2,3,4)) std::cout << x << " ";
std::cout << "\n";
for(auto x : make_from_doubles(1.0,1.5,2.0,2.5)) std::cout << x << " ";
```

> 1 2 3 4
>
> 1 1.5 2 2.5

[**live example on wandbox**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/vSwLIjqucC27OScg)

---

Note that I'm using a [C++17 *fold expression*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold) to check if all `Ts...` are of a particular type here:

```
static_assert((std::is_same<Ts, int>::value && ...));
```

If you do not have access to C++17 features, this can be easily replaced with something like:

```
template <typename... Ts>
constexpr auto all_true(Ts... xs)
{
    for(auto x : std::initializer_list<bool>{xs...}) 
        if(!x) return false;

    return true;
}

// ...

static_assert(all_true(std::is_same<Ts, int>{}...));
```

Comment: Is the `&& ...`  really literally that? What does it mean?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: apologies for not explaining that - it's a C++17 fold expression. Will improve my answer.

Comment: Instead of the fold expression, you could use `std::conjunction`, although admittedly `std::conjunction` is a C++ 17 feature. I do find it easier to read than the fold expression though: `std::conjunction<std::is_same<Ts, int>...>::value`